# Asynchronous scheduled job in Kotlin

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to understand which is the best way to have an asynchronous job fired at a scheduled rate in Kotlin, while the application is normally running it's normal tasks. Let's say I have a simple application that only prints out "..." every second, but every 5 seconds I want another job / thread / coroutine (which ever suits best) to print "you have a message!". For the async job I have a class `NotificationProducer` and it looks like this.

```
class NotificationProducer {

    fun produce() {
        println("You have a message!")
    }
}
```

Then, my main method looks like this.

```
    while (true) {
        println("...")
        sleep(1000)
    }
```

Should I use `GlobalScope.async`, `Timer().schedule(...)` or some Quartz job to achieve what I want? Any advice is highly appreciated. The point is that notification must come from another class (e.g. NotificationProducer)

Comment: I would recommend using Java standard approach - use `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool()` to create an executor, next use the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` to create a task. Note, an exception from a task Runnable cancels the execution, a try/catch may be needed

Comment: @EugenePetrenko, why not coroutines with the `delay` function execution?

Answer (score 6):

If I correctly understand the issue, using Kotlin Coroutines you can implement it as the following:

```
class Presenter : CoroutineScope { // implement CoroutineScope to create local scope
    private var job: Job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Default + job 

    // this method will help to stop execution of a coroutine. 
    // Call it to cancel coroutine and to break the while loop defined in the coroutine below    
    fun cancel() {
        job.cancel()
    }

    fun schedule() = launch { // launching the coroutine
        var seconds = 1
        val producer = NotificationProducer()
        while (true) {
            println("...")
            delay(1000)

            if (seconds++ == 5) {
                producer.produce()
                seconds = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use an instance of the `Presenter` class to launch the coroutine and stop it:

```
val presenter = Presenter()
presenter.schedule() // calling `schedule()` function launches the coroutine

//...

presenter.cancel() // cancel the coroutine when you need
```

Comment: Nice for me! here is my realization:
`interface IPresenter : CoroutineScope {
    val producers: Set<IProducer>
    val logger: Logger
    var jobs: CoroutineContext

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.IO + jobs

    fun cancel() {
        jobs.cancel()
    }

    fun schedule(intervalMillis: Long, producer: IProducer) {
        jobs += launch {
            while (true) {
                producer.produce()
                delay(intervalMillis)
            }
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 6):

For simple scheduling requirements, you can consider using coroutines:

```
class NotificationProducerScheduler(val service: NotificationProducer, val interval: Long, val initialDelay: Long?) :
    CoroutineScope {
    private val job = Job()

    private val singleThreadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + singleThreadExecutor.asCoroutineDispatcher()


    fun stop() {
        job.cancel()
        singleThreadExecutor.shutdown()
    }

    fun start() = launch {
        initialDelay?.let {
            delay(it)
        }
        while (isActive) {
            service.produce()
            delay(interval)
        }
        println("coroutine done")
    }
}
```

Otherwise, the Java concurrency API is pretty solid too:

```
class NotificationProducerSchedulerJavaScheduler(
    val service: NotificationProducer,
    val interval: Long,
    val initialDelay: Long = 0
) {

    private val scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)
    private val task = Runnable { service.produce() }

    fun stop() {
        scheduler.shutdown()
    }

    fun start() {
        scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, initialDelay, interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Im such a n00b with coroutines. But how do I start NotificationProducerScheduler ?

Answer (score 0):

This function will run a task in the background while proceeding with a "main" task that controls the lifecycle of the background job.  Below is an example of usage.

```kotlin
/**
 * Runs a task in the background in IO while the op proceeds.
 * The job is canceled when op returns.
 * This is useful for updating caches and the like.
 */
suspend fun withBackgroundTask(task: suspend () -> Unit, op: suspend () -> Unit) {
    val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { task() }
    try {
        op()
    } finally {
        job.cancel()
    }
}

/**
 * Updates the cache in a background task while op runs.
 */ 
suspend fun withCache(cache: Cache<*>, op: suspend () -> Unit) {
    suspend fun cacheUpdate() {
        cache.fetchInternal()
        while (true) {
            delay(cache.cycle)
            cache.fetchInternal()
        }
    }
    withBackgroundTask(::cacheUpdate, op)
}
```